# Can not import graph after transform_graph with quantize_nodes

Tags: python, tensorflow

bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph \

--in_graph="/home/.../mobilenet_v2.pb" \

--out_graph="/home/.../mobilenet_v2_clean.pb" \

--inputs=image_tensor\

--outputs="detection_boxes,detection_scores,detection_classes,num_detections"\

--transforms='add_default_attributes

strip_unused_nodes

remove_nodes(op=Identity, op=CheckNumerics)

fold_constants(ignore_errors=true)

fold_batch_norms

fold_old_batch_norms

quantize_weights

quantize_nodes

strip_unused_nodes

sort_by_execution_order'

I'm trying to quantize default ssd mobile model from tensorflow object_detection api.
After execution transformation as above, I can not import graph:

.....
.....

ValueError: Specified colocation to an op that does not exist during import: SecondStagePostprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/strided_slice in SecondStagePostprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/TensorArrayWrite_4/TensorArrayWriteV3/Enter